# Access Appcelerator Properties in an iOS module

Tags: javascript, ios, nsuserdefaults, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am attempting to save a property in javascript, and then access it in a native objective-c module. I am sure this is simple enough, but it isn't working for me. Here is the js:

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('testkey', 'testvalue');
```

And then in Obj-C:

```
for (NSString* key in [TiApp tiAppProperties])
{
    NSLog(@"[INFO] %@ = %@", key, [[TiApp tiAppProperties] objectForKey:key]);
}
```

A list of properties does print out, but none of my own. testkey is not there. Is there something I am not accounting for?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself. User added properties are added to [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]. TiApp tiAppProperties appears to be for the built-in settings only.